# ServiceStack Exception: 'Handler for Request not found' when trying to insert Entry to SqlLite db

Tags: .net, web-services, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm just learning how to use ServiceStack and I am  getting an exception that I can't get past and not sure what is causing the exception.  Here it is:

```
Handler for Request not found:    

Request.ApplicationPath: /
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /entry/5/11-11-2012
Request.FilePath: /entry/5/11-11-2012
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.MapPath('~'): C:\Projects\Tutorials\FirstServiceStackApp\FirstServiceStackApp\
Request.Path: /entry/5/11-11-2012
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.ResolvedPathInfo: /entry/5/11-11-2012
Request.PhysicalPath: C:\Projects\Tutorials\FirstServiceStackApp\FirstServiceStackApp\entry\5\11-11-2012
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath: C:\Projects\Tutorials\FirstServiceStackApp\FirstServiceStackApp\
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /entry/5/11-11-2012
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri: http://localhost:52920/entry/5/11-11-2012
Request.Url.AbsolutePath: /entry/5/11-11-2012
Request.Url.Fragment: 
Request.Url.Host: localhost
Request.Url.LocalPath: /entry/5/11-11-2012
Request.Url.Port: 52920
Request.Url.Query: 
Request.Url.Scheme: http
Request.Url.Segments: System.String[]
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: True
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: C:\Projects\Tutorials\FirstServiceStackApp\FirstServiceStackApp
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [entry.cs,entryservice.cs,firstservicestackapp.csproj,firstservicestackapp.csproj.user,global.asax,global.asax.cs,packages.config,recordipfilter.cs,statusquery.cs,statusservice.cs,web.config,web.debug.config,web.release.config,app_data,bin,obj,properties,scripts,x64,x86]
App.DefaultHandler: metadata
App.DebugLastHandlerArgs: GET|/entry/5/11-11-2012|C:\Projects\Tutorials\FirstServiceStackApp\FirstServiceStackApp\entry\5\11-11-2012
```

I'm going through John Sonmez's excellent Pluralsight course on ServiceStack, and have just added the OrmLite piece to my project.  This exception is thrown when I attempt to add a new Entry.  So I have no SqlLite file yet in my App_Data folder, and none is created.  It's not breaking in the code when I try to debug, so not sure where to look for this...

**Edit: Added relevant Source Code:**

```
[Route("/entry/{Amount}/{EntryTime}", "POST")]
public class Entry { ... }

public class EntryService : Service 
{ 
    public TrackedDataRepository TDRepository { get; set; } 

    public object Any(Entry request) 
    { 
        var id = TDRepository.AddEntry(request); 
        return new EntryResponse {Id = id}; 
    } 
}
```

**Solution:**

Remove **POST** filter on Route definition so it applies to all routes:

```
[Route("/entry/{Amount}/{EntryTime}")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm - Not sure this is a OrmLite issue. If I understand the exception message correctly it is hinting that you don't have a 'service class**' with the correct method included on it. In this case since the HttpMethod is Get your service class would need to have a Get (or Any) method on it.

Do you have a 'service class' like below.

```
public class EntryService : Service //make sure inheriting from Service or RestServiceBase<Entry> 
{
    public object Get(Entry request)
    {
        //handle request here
    }
}
```

**Update 1:** 
You will also need to have your Entry class 'routed' correctly. In your case since your are adding 2 parameters (/5/11-11-2012) you'll need 2 route parameters (or one with a wildcard).

```
[Route("/Entry/{P1}/{P2}")] //or use /Entry/{P1*} to use wildcard
public class Entry
{
    public string P1 {get; set;}
    public string P2 {get; set;}
}
```

**service class is your class that inherits from Service/RestServiceBase and it is what 'handles' your request (in this case Entry) and returns your response (generally following the name convention of {request}Response eg.EntryResponse).

Comment: Yes, I do have a very simple EntryService class.  Here's the code for it:
`
    public class EntryService : Service
    {
        public TrackedDataRepository TDRepository { get; set; }

        public object Any(Entry request)
        {
            var id = TDRepository.AddEntry(request);
            return new EntryResponse {Id = id};
        }
    }
`
  Is that the problem?  (Sorry, backticks don't seem to be formatting my code in the comment...)

Comment: Your service class looks correct. Please see update above. Could be your route.

Comment: That was it.  I had the route in there, but had added POST to the call, so a GET wouldn't work.  When I went to check the route I noticed it looked like this:  `[Route("/entry/{Amount}/{EntryTime}", "POST")]`, so I changed it to `[Route("/entry/{Amount}/{EntryTime}")]` and now it works.  Thanks!